# Flux through sphere symmetry?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, symmetry, surface-integrals

Is the flux through a sphere centered at the origin of the vector field $\boldsymbol{F} = (-x,1,z)$ equal to $0$? If so, is there any simple symmetry which suggests it? I have done the calculation which yielded a very complicated integral but it turned out to be $0$ (I should hope). I just want to know if there is any easy way of seeing this?

Comment: Did you check by using the [divergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem#Mathematical_statement)? It should tell you pretty quickly whether you are correct or not. The example in the Wiki page pretty much does your question for you.

Comment: the divergence is 1+0-1= 0 conveniently? So the integral of divergence is 0? (we are integrating with limits) Is this a correct line of reasoning

Comment: Yes, the divergence theorem shows the integral to equal $0$.